# Mint - Stored SVN password was changed and now unable to commit

Tags: linux, svn, linux-mint

I have a copy of a repo on my localhost with a saved username / password for the SVN repo.

The problem is that I changed my svn password (and would like to keep it that way) but every time I try to svn commit, it is asking for my GNOME keyring password (which I enter correctly). This is odd in the first place because I never had it ask me this before.

Then, after entering my password to the keyring, I get this error message:

> svn: OPTIONS of 'PATH_TO_CHANGED_FILES': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (REPO_URL)

This is happening on 2 repos that I have but a 3rd one is just fine.

When I disable authentication on the server, everything commits just fine and if I try to update / commit from another server, it also works just fine.

I tried adding the following lines to my ~/.subversion/servers:

> store-passwords = no
>
> store-plaintext-passwords = no

And I also tried adding the following lines to my ~/.subversion/config:

> store-passwords = no
>
> store-auth-creds = no

But those config file changes do nothing.

Is there a way for my localhost svn to forget the username and passwords I have entered for these repos (they were saved before) so I can get back to everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by deleting the keyring file for MATE. It is a bit of a brute way of doing it but it worked. You can delete the keyring file for MATE with the following command:

```
rm ~/.config/mate/keyrings/*.keyring
```

Comment: I am afraid this solution is only valid if you only keep this password in the keyring. In most cases it is probably not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, how to remove stored data from keyring (old  pass for repo), but you can try *to replace it*.

Use in console any SVN command, which will require authentication with additional options

```
Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
```

and test repo-communication in usual way after it

About keyring pass-request:

Check settings in `~/.subversion/config`, `[auth]` section for `password-stores =`

Check settings in `~/.subversion/servers`, `[global]` section for

```
store-passwords =
store-plaintext-passwords =
```

Comment: I have tried all of those but the same problem exists. I am not sure if this is a server side issue though since disabling authentication solves the problem. Just guessing though.

Comment: @shiznatix - did you check (just in case) `~/.subversion/auth/` tree?

Comment: yes, I deleted the folder entirely and even though it is re-created, the same problem exists.

Comment: @shiznatix - if with preliminary correct username/pass options in command you get auth error: edit user on server side, again? Or check current credentials, using the same auth-file in another location for pure http-access